# Why is $a+(a+r)+(a+2r)+\cdots+(n-2r)+(n-r)+n=\frac{(n+a)\cdot(n-a+r)}{2r}$?

Tags: summation, proof-explanation

Let $a, k, p, r$ and $n$ be all members of $\mathbb{Z}$. $p$ is an arbitrary number such that $a+pr=n$

Why does the statement below hold true?

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{p}(a+kr)
&=a+(a+r)+(a+2r)+\cdots+\left(a+(p-2)r\right)+\left(a+(p-1)r\right)+(a+pr)\\
&=a+(a+r)+(a+2r)+\cdots+(n-2r)+(n-r)+n\\
&=\color{red}{\frac{(n+a)\cdot(n-a+r)}{2r}}
\end{align}

I don't understand the highlighted transformation. I understand that $(n+a)$ should be a factor as it is the sum of two numbers, one from the lower and other from the higher end, e.g. $(n-r)+(a+r)=n+a$.

However, I was unable to keep up with the rest of the operation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Uh...where did the $p$ go?

Comment: $n$ is the last term of the finite sum, so $n=a+pr$.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Forgot about that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formulas of arithmetic progrssion. The given sequence is an arithmetic progression; first term $=a$, last term $=n$, common difference $=r$

$\text{number of terms }\\=\dfrac{\text{last term}-\text{first term}}{\text{common difference}}+1\\=\dfrac{n-a}{r}+1$

$\text{Sum }\\=\dfrac{\text{number of terms}}{2}(\text{first term}+\text{last term})\\=\dfrac{\dfrac{n-a}{r}+1}{2}(a+n)\\=\dfrac{n-a+r}{2r}(a+n)$

Comment: Thank you for the layman's explanation, that made things much easier to understand. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

One may note that

$$\sum_{k=0}^pa=\underbrace{a+a+a+\dots+a}_{p+1}=a(p+1)$$

and likewise,

$$\sum_{k=0}^pkr=r\left(1+2+3+\dots+p\right)\\=r\frac{p(p+1)}2$$

Comment: Thanks for the input! The sum of the two would essentially be the same thing that @Kiran found, only a different representation, no?

Comment: @Glycerius Yup.  But it should come out to be the same with some greasing.

Comment: Understood. Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: :D You too!  :-)